# Ember.js not sending data to the template/view in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I am learning **Ember.js** as we speak and what I am trying to do is to integrate it into a **Rails** application (vanilla app, just for playing around), since most of the time I'm working with Rails. So far so good, I managed to install it (I am using `ember-rails`), but I encountered a small problem and it seems I cannot figure it out, even if I watched (I suppose) every tutorial about Ember and Rails out there.

So, the problem is that I cannot make the router pass any kind of data to the view/template. I even hardcoded there a JSON object (and not rely on the adapter) to see if this works, but with no success. So, my code looks like this:

**Rails Gemfile `Gemfile`**:

```
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source'
gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

**Rails controller `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @a_users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render :json => @a_users}
    end
  end
end
```

**Rails model `app/models/users.rb`**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true
end
```

**Rails serializer `app/serializers/user_serializer.rb`**:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :first_name, :last_name
end
```

**Rails routes `config/routes.rb`**

```
NewEmberOnRails::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'
  resources :users
end
```

And this pretty much covers the Rails part. If I go and visit `localhost:3000/users.json` I get a nice formatted JSON object on this format (consider I have a John Doe user in the database):
`{"users":[{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}]}`

The Ember.js part, I have written as following:

**Ember store `app/assets/javascripts/store.js`**

```
NewEmberOnRails.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  // Override the default adapter with the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` which
  // is built to work nicely with the ActiveModel::Serializers gem.
  adapter: DS.ActiveModelAdapter
  // revision: 11,
  // url: 'http://localhost:3000'
});
```

I even played around with `revision` and `url` but nothing.

**Ember router `app/assets/javascripts/router.js`**

```
NewEmberOnRails.Router.map(function() {
  return this.resource('users');
});
```

**Ember route `app/assets/javascripts/route.rb`**

```
NewEmberOnRails.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // return this.get('store').find('user');
    return {users: [{
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe"
    }, {
      first_name: "Big",
      last_name: "Bang"
    }]};
  }
});
```

**As you can see, I've commented the store here, and returned a hardcoded object here, but nothing.**

**Ember controller `app/assets/javascripts/controller/users.js`**

```
NewEmberOnRails.usersController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  resourceType: NewEmberOnRails.User
});
```

**Ember model `app/assets/javascripts/model/user.js`**

```
var attr = DS.attr;

NewEmberOnRails.User = DS.Model.extend(
  first_name = attr(),
  last_name = attr()
);
```

And finally, the views, Rails and Ember together (I guess I'm doing something wrong here, but I cannot figure it out what):

**Rails users view `app/views/users/index.html.erb`**

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ view NewEmberOnRails.ListUsersView }}
</script>
```

So, this is calling the Ember view, here (`app/assets/javascripts/views/users/list.js`):

```
NewEmberOnRails.ListUsersView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'users/users',
  usersBinding: 'NewEmberOnRails.usersController'
});
```

That is using the `users` template here (`app/assets/javascripts/template/users/users.handlebars`):

```
{{#each users}}
  {{view NewEmberOnRails.ShowUserView userBinding="this"}}
{{else}}
  No users!
{{/each}}
```

Now, in `ShowUserView` I have (`app/assets/javascripts/views/users/show.js`):

```
NewEmberOnRails.ShowUserView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'users/show'
});
```

And is rendering this template (`app/assets/javascripts/templates/users/show.handlebars`)

```
First Name: {{user.first_name}}
```

**So, to wrap up everything**... when I access `localhost:3000/users` I only get `No users!`, witch lead me to two possibilities:

1. I do not have any `users` array at the time I'm iterating through it in `app/assets/javascripts/template/users/users.handlebars`
2. I have it, but is empty, so there is a problem between the route and my views/templates.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What versions of ember/ember data are you using?  Does the app attempt a network request to the endpoint?  If so is it hitting `users` or `users.json`?

Comment: Do you get any plain html from your ember views?  I don't see an Application being created

Comment: I am using `ember-rails` version `0.14.1`. This gives me Ember version `1.3.0`, Ember Data version `0.14`, all on jQuery `1.10.2` (from `jquery-rails 3.0.4`). No, I forgot to mention this. The app do not attempt any request when hitting `users`.

The app is created in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. Is something like `NewEmberOnRails = Ember.Application.create();`. There are no errors returned from client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it however you wish, of course, but if it were mine, I would have my route return an array and make my controller extend `ArrayController`.  Seems simpler and will match what you are really going to get from the store (collection of `User`).  Unless you really want to return a single object containing an array, this is counter to 'normal' Ember Data usage--

In the code in `NewEmberOnRails.UsersRoute`, you have commented out the `store.find` and replaced it with something that is *not* the same thing...  Try this:

```
NewEmberOnRails.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // return this.get('store').find('user');
    return [{
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe"
    }, {
      first_name: "Big",
      last_name: "Bang"
    }];
  }
});
```

and:

```
NewEmberOnRails.usersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    resourceType: NewEmberOnRails.User
});
```